# Java array null pointer after 3499 elements

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, max

I have a piece of code that is ment to scan in a large array of numbers (as integers) and store them into a scenario object. However after I get to the 3499th object (it prints the 3498th J) it crashes with a null pointer. I looked for a maximum array size but couldn't find anything on the internet except 2^32-5 however I'm not even close to that limit.

```
        in1scan = new Scanner(in1);
        in2scan = new Scanner(in2);
        scenario[] ret= new scenario[9999];
        int j=0;

        while (in1scan.hasNext()){
            String[] input=(in1scan.next().split(",", 16));
                    ret[j]=new scenario();
            for (int i=0; i<16;i++){

                ret[j].input[i]=Integer.parseInt((input[i]));   
            }
            j++;
        }

        j=0;
        while (in2scan.hasNext()){
            ret[j].correct=Integer.parseInt(in2scan.next()); //here things go wrong
            j++;
            System.out.println(j);
        }
```

Does anybody know what is wrong? And yes I know that I can use nextInt instead of the current roundabout way of accepting numbers but I'm going to add some extra functionality that requires it to be handled this way.

Comment: I think your second input (that one scanned by `in2scan`) might be larger than your first one. To be sure, you'd have to post a stacktrace.

Comment: We need a stack trace to see exacly where it fails. It always helps.

Comment: Do you maybe have more `correct` than `input`? Because you are only creating a new scenario object in the first loop so if you have more `correct` you cant access `ret[j].correct`.

Comment: On the line that says here things go wrong I get an java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Questions: what is with this line `for (int i=0; i<16;i++){`? to me it looks like you create 16 times new scenario object for current j.

Comment: enter that was indeed not quite correct moved the scenario creationg from that loop but the error remains the same.

Comment: It's getting a null pointer exception, not an array index out of bounds.  I'm guessing there are more in2 objects than in1 objects.

Answer (score 6):

You have "run out" of ret.

In this part of the code you create the first `in1scan.size()` elements of `ret`

```
    while (in1scan.hasNext()){
        String[] input=(in1scan.next().split(",", 16));
        for (int i=0; i<16;i++){
            ret[j]=new scenario();
            ret[j].input[i]=Integer.parseInt((input[i]));   
        }
        j++;
    }
```

Here you use the first `in2scan.size()` element of `ret`. If `in2scan.size() > in1scan.size()` then `ret[j]` will be null and so `.correct` cannot be called upon it

```
    j=0;
    while (in2scan.hasNext()){
        ret[j].correct=Integer.parseInt(in2scan.next()); //here things go wrong
        j++;
        System.out.println(j);
    }
```

Stepping through in a debugger will (hopefully) confirm this

Comment: It does indeed look like ret[j] somehow ran out while it shouldn't (if everything goes right ret[j] should have been big enough).

Comment: @Thijser Do you guarantee somewhere that in1scan.size()==in2scan.size()?

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace tells you the exception is thrown at

```
        ret[j].correct=Integer.parseInt(in2scan.next()); //here things go wrong
```

so either `ret`, `ret[j]` or `in2scan` is null.

To find out which it is, set an exception breakpoint for NullPointerException, and run the program in debug mode. That will suspend execution at the time the exception is thrown, allowing you to inspect program state at that time.

Comment: Only one is possible on the not-first-loop and in2scan.hasNext() being true. ret[j] must be null

Comment: Likely. But what is j, and why is ret[j] null? Looking at the local variables in the debugger is likely to yield valuable clues. It is also good practice for when the program is too complicated to find the bug simply by looking at code ...

Comment: Certainly true, you'll find no arguments from me against using the debugger

Answer (score 1):

`i<16` should be `i < input.length`. As `split(.., 16) only specifies a max.

Comment: Good point, I thought the same, unless this input which is split always has 16 length.

Comment: Must be an error in the input data, and even if there "always" are 16 values, one of the values on line 34999 could contain an EBCDIC newline (NEL) and be read partially, or whatever. Then higher elements are null.